# How to tell intellij to highlight a string as HTML?

Tags: intellij-idea

Usually in intellij is automatically detects that a string is HTML, in which case intellij knows to highlight the string as HTML, making the tags in a special color etc.

But every now and then I come across a string which contains HTML but it is not highlighted.

How can I manually tell intellij to identify the string as HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You can [configure a custom code injection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/using-language-injections.html) using [intention action](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/intention-actions.html) for the string:

[image: injection]